# How long should I wait for a headhunter to contact a company?

Tags: recruitment

I am wondering how long to wait for a headhunter to get back to me about a job that they approached me with.

Three weeks ago I got a call, I met the headhunter less than a week later where it was stated that I would hear something in a few days. A few business days go by, I get back in touch and am I told that the individual I met with no longer works with the company and that someone else will contact the company offering the job. A week later I ask the status and am told they are about to contact the company offering the job. It's been about a week since then and I've heard nothing.

When I met with the headhunter I was given the name of the company offering the job and I'm wondering when it becomes acceptable to contact the company myself?

I don't want to step on anybody's toes and I don't want to mess with a potential interview with the company offering the job but nothing stated by the headhunter has occurred in the time frames they've given.

Answer (score 5):

It's harmless to send an email to the headhunter so don't worry about bothering them. You are money to him so even if you're a minor pain in the butt he won't care because if you get placed by him, it's all become worth it.

It's a sad fact that most headhunters/recruiters suck.By that I mean the vast majority only talk to you when they have something positive to say or if they want something from you.  This means that there are often lags between communication from them if they have nothing to tell you, even though we all know that a simple email once a week saying, "Just keeping in touch, I still haven't heard from them" is all it will take to keep you happy.

In summary, you can pester a bit, just don't be a pest. A week without response is certainly long enough. Just send a quick query and not a book and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Ex-headhunter here. (Mainly tech industry roles, Director level and above)

I think you may be giving this situation, and this firm, a little bit more respect than is deserved.

Here's the context in which you are making this decision:

To a recruitment firm, you're essentially a name in a database. If that name comes up in search as a potential candidate, you temporarily become an important asset, but only for as long as you remain in the running for a role. While it's unfair to paint all headhunters as ruthless mercenaries, as is often done, few of them have truly have your career development in mind.

You could say that this firm has dropped the ball when it comes to your case. Letting you know the details of the role early on, and now giving you the runaround when it comes to maintaining contact. It should be in their best interest to "keep you warm", even if they are scrambling on their end to reorganize after the departure of your recruiter.

*How you proceed here, I think, depends on whether the position is posted publicly not.*

If it's an open posting, then screw the recruiters - you owe them nothing. The likelihood of repercussion is slim. Them missing out on the chance to present you to their client is their problem, not yours.

If it's a closed position, it's slightly different situation. There are two main potential risks.

1) The person at the company that hired this recruitment firm (and possibly others) 
will be expecting applications through those channels, and you risk not getting your application on their desk.

2) You "step on someones toes" as you put it. This should only be a concern if you think this recruitment firm is going to play a big part in finding your next role, either this one or another. By going around them, there a small chance you'll make someone there look bad, or lose favor, and that may negatively impact your standing with them.

*If I was in your shoes I would do the following:*

If the position is posted publicly, stop losing time and apply for it now.

If you can't find the position on the company's site or elsewhere, then write to the recruiters and say something along the lines of "It's been *n* been days/weeks since I heard anything from you, and I'm growing increasingly concerned that I'll miss out on this opportunity, so I'm going to move ahead with my application, thanks." If that doesn't motivate a reply, then you really have nothing to care about.

Give them a couple of days. If you get nothing back, apply to company as best you can, and say something like "I was a candidate with X recruting firm, but some personnel issues there have lead to complications and hold ups, so I'm applying to you directly out of concern that I'll miss this opportunity".

Bottom line: Take a note of the recruiters book and be a bit more ruthless about this. Remember that even if you step on toes, you're probably still going to get the call from them if you look like a perfect match for the next role they're trying to fill.